# Returning list of values as text string in one column from sub query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

In postgresql its possible to return value in one column, for instance  - comma separated list, that includes returned values from one sub select
This is very useful in cases when dealing with large amount of data and trying to avoid multiple sub queries

```
SELECT a.key, a.transaction_id,
array_to_string(array(SELECT cast(lo.issue as text) FROM keys.key_list lo 
WHERE version_id = 2 AND lo.issue >= '2017-01-01' 
AND lo.key=a.key),\', \') as issue_dates
FROM public.orders a
WHERE a.type IN (2, 4)
```

In this case it returns data in like

```
    key | transaction_id  | issue_dates

   aaa1 |   234234234     | 2017-01-01, 2017-06-05, 2018-01-02
```

Is it possible to do similar thing in MySQL?

Comment: You can use group_concat but i prefer to do this kind of manipulation in application code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.key, a.transaction_id,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(lo.issue) 
FROM keys.key_list lo WHERE version_id = 2 AND lo.issue >= '2017-01-01' 
AND lo.key=a.key) as issue_dates
FROM public.orders a
WHERE a.type IN (2, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function in MySQL to aggregate a list of values as a string.  You don't need to write a subselect for that, a left join will do nicely.